# Regex parse Html how to repeat code block

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extra food entries from the html below, when I use the regex it seems to grab only the first food entry for each section, I was wondering how I can repeat the logic to grab all the rows within a section? Also how would I make the points part optional sometimes it's not available for each row?

Any help would be appreciated

**Output:**

```
<span class="sectiontitle">Medium Pan Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>\r\n12" Medium Pan Pizza: Cheese\r\n    (270 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts">  6.5</span><br>   <span class="sectiontitle">Medium Pan Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>\r\n12" Medium Pan Pizza: Cheese\r\n    (270 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts">  6.5</span><br>   Medium Pan Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br> 12" Medium Pan Pizza: Cheese    (270 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts">  6.5</span><br>
<span class="sectiontitle">Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>\r\n12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Cheese\r\n    (200 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>  <span class="sectiontitle">Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>\r\n12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Cheese\r\n    (200 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>  Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>  12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Cheese (200 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
<span class="sectiontitle">Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>\r\n12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Cheese\r\n    (230 cal/10 g fat/1 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5 </span><br>
```

**Regex:**

```
<span class="sectiontitle">(?<Name>.*)\s*(?<ServingName>.*)\s*(?<ServingInfo>\((?<Calories>.*?) cal/(?<Fat>.*?) g fat/(?<Fiber>.*?) g fiber/(?<Carbs>.*?) g carbs\) <span class="blackpts">\s*(?<Points>.*?)\s*</span>)
```

**HTML:**

```
<p><span class="sectiontitle">Medium Pan Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Cheese
    (270 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts">  6.5</span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Pepperoni
    (280 cal/14 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Supreme
    (310 cal/16 g fat/2 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Pepperoni & Mushroom
    (260 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Italian Sausage & Red Onion
    (300 cal/15 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Quartered Ham & Pineapple
    (250 cal/11 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Meat Lover's
    (370 cal/22 g fat/2 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 9 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Veggie Lover's
    (250 cal/11 g fat/2 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Super Supreme
    (330 cal/17 g fat/2 g fiber/29 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Chicken Supreme
    (270 cal/12 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Pepperoni Lover's
    (330 cal/18 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 8 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Sausage Lover's
    (360 cal/20 g fat/2 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 8.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Bacon
    (300 cal/16 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Beef
    (300 cal/15 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Chicken
    (280 cal/12 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Ham
    (250 cal/11 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Italian Sausage
    (320 cal/18 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Pork
    (310 cal/16 g fat/2 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Black Olives
    (260 cal/12 g fat/2 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Pan Pizza: Pineapple
    (250 cal/11 g fat/1 g fiber/29 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
    <span class="sectiontitle">Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Cheese
    (200 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Pepperoni
    (210 cal/10 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Supreme
    (230 cal/11 g fat/1 g fiber/22 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Pepperoni & Mushroom
    (190 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Italian Sausage & Red Onion
    (230 cal/11 g fat/1 g fiber/23 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Quartered Ham & Pineapple
    (180 cal/6 g fat/1 g fiber/23 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Meat Lover's
    (310 cal/18 g fat/1 g fiber/22 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Veggie Lover's
    (180 cal/7 g fat/1 g fiber/23 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Super Supreme
    (250 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/23 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Chicken Supreme
    (200 cal/7 g fat/1 g fiber/22 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Pepperoni Lover's
    (260 cal/14 g fat/1 g fiber/22 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Sausage Lover's
    (280 cal/16 g fat/1 g fiber/22 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Bacon
    (240 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Beef
    (230 cal/11 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Chicken
    (210 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Ham
    (180 cal/7 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Italian Sausage
    (250 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/21 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Pork
    (230 cal/12 g fat/1 g fiber/22 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Black Olives
    (190 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/22 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Thin 'N Crispy Pizza: Pineapple
    (180 cal/6 g fat/1 g fiber/24 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4 </span><br>
    <span class="sectiontitle">Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza - 1 slice / 1/8th pizza</span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Cheese
    (230 cal/10 g fat/1 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Pepperoni
    (240 cal/11 g fat/1 g fiber/24 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Supreme
    (270 cal/13 g fat/2 g fiber/26 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Pepperoni & Mushroom
    (230 cal/9 g fat/1 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Italian Sausage & Red Onion
    (260 cal/12 g fat/1 g fiber/26 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Quartered Ham & Pineapple
    (220 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/26 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Meat Lover's
    (340 cal/19 g fat/1 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 8 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Veggie Lover's
    (210 cal/8 g fat/2 g fiber/26 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Super Supreme
    (280 cal/13 g fat/2 g fiber/29 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Chicken Supreme
    (230 cal/7 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Pepperoni Lover's
    (290 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Sausage Lover's
    (310 cal/16 g fat/2 g fiber/28 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 7 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Bacon
    (260 cal/13 g fat/1 g fiber/24 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Beef
    (260 cal/12 g fat/2 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Chicken
    (240 cal/9 g fat/1 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Ham
    (210 cal/6 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Italian Sausage
    (280 cal/14 g fat/1 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6.5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Pork
    (270 cal/13 g fat/2 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 6 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Black Olives
    (220 cal/9 g fat/2 g fiber/25 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 5 </span><br>
12" Medium Hand-Tossed Pizza: Pineapple
    (210 cal/8 g fat/1 g fiber/27 g carbs) <span class="blackpts"> 4.5 </span><br>
</p>
```

Comment: **Epic** answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: To clarify, several times a day people ask how to parse html using regular expressions. This is not a job for regex. You should use an xml parser.

Comment: What tool/language are you using to try and match with?  Some languages like PHP have things like `preg_match_all()` that do this automagically.

Comment: I'm using C#, I'm going to try using the HTML Agility pack, it's just this html above doesn't have a good structure most of it is text nodes so if I wanna grab the cal, the fat, the fiber etc etc I'm guessing I could use regex for that part which I have already figured out. My question is more about how to get blocks at a time

<span class="sectiontitle">Block1</span>
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT
<span class="sectiontitle">Block1</span>
TEXT
TEXT

Basically I want get the block with corresponding span with it's TEXT elements